# Slide to side with jquery on click and toggle

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, slide

So i have a site where i need to have a div slide in from side with a click from a button (slide in from left and slide out on right) - and on reclick it should slide out again... So it needs to be hidden from pageload and only become visible once the button is clicked.

I try to make this, but im new to jquery, so if someone could help me proceed, i would appreciate it.

here is a fiddle of how far i am now.

LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/zes8a/21/

**Jquery**:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {   
$('#div1').slideToggle('slow', function() {  
});
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Click</a></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#div1 {
width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#F30; color:#FFF; text-align:center; font-size:30px;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#btn').click(function() {   
    $('#div1').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zes8a/39/

Comment: Nice! Is there an easy way to make the div slide in/out from the other side of the page?

Comment: You can use `float:right` or `right:0` depends on your HTML markup.