# How to make an outside div come from left on click and on ri-click go to right with jQuery toggle and animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The menu works ok, but have no animation. I want the `.fullpagenav` on click comes out from the left to right, and when re-clicked returns back (from right to left). It was great if you can do it with toggle and animation, only for the short code.

I found this code on the following topic: [Slide to side with jquery on click and toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600473/slide-to-side-with-jquery-on-click-and-toggle)

So, I have this following code:

```js
 $( ".secondary-toggle" ).click(function() {
    $('.fullpagenav').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
 });
```

```css
    .fullpagenav {
 position:fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color:#464646;
 display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullpagenav">
   <div id="secondary" class="secondary toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
         ...
     </nav>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: read about jquery animate here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I'm not so good in english.. I have difficult to understand what this pages mean.. I can only see the examples, but all the rest of documentation I really don't understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code above doesn't working, I create similiar code for you, to show You how could it be done. Its simply code, if you dont understand something, just ask me.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.menu-item', function(e) {
  var self = $(e.currentTarget);
  self.toggleClass('menu-item-toggle')
  });
</script>
<style>
  .menu-item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 2s;
  }
  .menu-item-toggle {
    left: 100px;
  }
</style>

<div class="menu-item">Menu item</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7076ja4/

Comment: This one look like what I want, but, if I have a separate button to click? Because my menu need to be hidden (or only out of page) and when I click my button, the div need to do what you did above (so, slide to left, and on ri-click, go to right)

Comment: Here I gave code explaintation https://jsfiddle.net/kesLwo7o/
Width that you should fit code to your needs.
If i help, please set "best answer" option ;]

Comment: Yes, you solved my problem! Love you lol. Can only you explain me excatly what is "toggle"? I think this is what alternate something, right? And, why ".click" method is not the same of ".on('click'...)"? So I vote you the best lovely answer!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set it at the left most of the page and then create a class having position left:0 and then toggle that class on click and for the effects use transition.

```js
 $( ".secondary-toggle" ).click(function() {
       if($(this).hasClass('active_nav')){
          $('.fullpagenav').removeClass('active_nav');
       }
       else{
          $('.fullpagenav').addClass('active_nav');
       }
       
 });
```

```css
    .fullpagenav {
 position:fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color:#464646;
 left:-100%;
    transition: all 1s linear 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear 1s;
    
    }
    .active_nav{
        left:0!important;
        transition: all 1s linear 1s;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s linear 1s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s linear 1s;
    
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullpagenav">
   <div id="secondary" class="secondary toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
         ...
     </nav>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This work fine on start, but when I click to close, it doesn't close :(

Answer (score 0):

I placed the `fullpagenav` div to left most and on click on that div animates as you requested.

Below is the updated code

```js
 $( ".fullpagenav" ).click(function() {
      $('.secondary').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

```css
    .fullpagenav {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 1%;
        margin-left: -1%;
    }
    
    .secondary {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 10%;
        background-color: #464646;
        display: none;
        padding-left: 1%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fullpagenav">
   <div id="secondary" class="secondary toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
         ...
     </nav>
   </div>
    </div>
```